# Using my own template parameters for std::mersenne_twister_engine when switching between different floating point precisions

Tags: c++, c++11, random, mersenne-twister

[`std::mt19937`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/) is a typedef of [`std::mersenne_twister_engine`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mersenne_twister_engine/). Should I be using my own template parameters for the latter if I'm switching between different floating point precisions in my sampling? If so, how?

Right now I have something like this

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using float_type = double;

    std::random_device rd;  
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float_type> dis(1.0, 2.0);
    for (int n = 0; n < 1e6; ++n) {
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

but when I switch `using float_type = double;` to `using float_type = float;` there isn't much of a speedup. Actually, in some other code I have, using `float` is actually much slower!

Here's a makefile if it helps. I used `time ./prog` after I compile with `make` as a rough timer, and I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and my processor is a Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E3-1241 v3 @ 3.50GHz × 8 .

```
PROG = prog
SRCS = main.cpp
OBJS = main.o
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -O3 $(INCLUDES) -pg


all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS) 

main.cpp :
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c 

main.o : main.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Any performance change between `uniform_real_distribution<float>` and `uniform_real_distribution<double>` will be obliterated by the cost of using `cout`. If you store your timings in an array you'll be able to actually do a performance comparison.

Comment: The stock `std::mt19937` should work for you.  We'd have to see your other code to tell you why it gets slower using a `float` instead of a `double`.  For this code it is IO bound so there really shouldn't be any change in the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be using my own template parameters for the latter if I'm switching between different floating point precisions in my sampling? If so, how?

Sure, you could use 64bit engine for sampling doubles (mantissa is 53bit long) and 32bit engine for sampling floats.

```
#define USE_DOUBLES

...

#ifdef USE_DOUBLES
    using float_type = double;
    using rng        = std::mt19937_64;
#else
    using float_type = float;
    using rng        = std::mt19937;
#endif
```

[mt19937_64](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937_64/) is alias for MT with generated 64bits of randomness per call